# strange behaviour in recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Could someone explain why the second function doesn't bring us a stack overflow?

```
//stack overflow on call
function test1() {
    test1();
}
//no stack overflow, nor beer
function test2() {
    setTimeout(test2, -500); //back to the future
}
```

Comment: The key is to realize that `setTimeout()` **always returns immediately**, and passing a negative number is treated as if you passed the minimum interval, probably at least 15 milliseconds.

Comment: No problem on this but thanks for the inside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's not recursive. The `test2` function is able to return, and some time later another invocation is scheduled by `setTimeout` via the anonymous function that was created.

Obviously, you can't go back in time. `setTimeout` has a minimum duration.

---

FWIW, the anonymous function is unnecessary. You could do `setTimeout(test2, -500)`.

Comment: "Obviously, you can't go back in time." You serious?

Comment: @roasted What do you expect `-500` to do?

Comment: To give 0, of course. Or brings me to 70's in California where to get some fun... :)

Comment: @roasted: Even a `0` duration would still be asynchronous. The `test2` function would be able to return before the function passed to `setTimeout` would be invoked.

Comment: @roasted even a zero timeout will cause a brief delay. No browser immediately calls the callback before returning from `setTimeout()`, in other words.

Comment: Ya, that makes sense. Even its not freezing UI, even on IE. Isn't it strange?

Comment: @roasted: IE has had in the past a little longer minimum duration. Something like `13ms`. I'm not sure about the newer versions. Depending on the overhead of the actual code being invoked, it could very well freeze the UI.